# Can I cast an object to a string from an object array of strings. Getting classCastException

Tags: java, arrays, string, object, classcastexception

I'm probably being very silly, but it's driving me nuts. I have searched around but am relatively new to programming and am in over my head. Please help if you can! the bar parameter is taking an arraylist.toArray() and it's just full of strings.

```
public bar(Object[] contents) {

    for (Object o : contents) {
        String s = (String) o;
        if (s == null) {
            System.out.println("newline"); //checking
        } else  {
            try {
                arrayContents.add(new line(s));

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("error printing note: " + s + " " + ex + " in bar " + i);
            }
        }
        i++;

    }
//        System.out.println(arrayContents);
}
```

Comment: Is it an `ArrayList<String>`? Also, post your full stack trace.

Comment: It wasn't but the below answer is perfect. I will post stack trace in future

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this instead

```
    String s = String.valueOf(o);
```

You cannot cast an Object to String if it is not a String object. You'll need to invoke `toString` method on the object instead - unless the object is `null`. `String.valueOf()` takes care of that

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```